# Is there a conditional CSS If for outlook?

Tags: html, css, email

I need some particular css for an html email, but only in outlook.

I'm looking for the outlook equivalent of
    `<!--[if IE]>body {background-color:red} <![endif]-->`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]
 // This CSS will only be seen in Outlook 2007
![endif]-->
```

Comment: Just Outlook or any office application?

Comment: I've only used it to target Outlook. Can't find documentation stating support for the rest of office apps.

Comment: worked like a charm. targeting phones was not working. so now having phones be the default and outlook pick up overrides to make everything bigger, works awesome.